# How to use Fandango APIs?

Tags: ios, api, integration, movies

I am trying to integrate with [Fandango](https://developer.fandango.com). I registered and created an API key on the portal, but the API key status is showing as "waiting" for two days.

[image: portal]

I get an error like

> Developer Inactive error.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the same issue right now.

Comment: Same here, any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Support for it seems terrible, I scoured their website looking for any point of contact about this. Nothing.

Comment: @MasonWolters  Sorry no luck...couldnt make it work...

Comment: You shouldn't display your API key on the public internet. You should revoke that particular key, ASAP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fandango does not currently have a public API.  There used to be a forum and somebody had asked about this.  This is from memory, but they stated that they currently only offer the API to partners.  Registration seems to be disabled now.

In the link, "Check out a summary of what we can help you offer your customers below." also suggests they only work with companies.

Answer (score 4):

Fandango's API is now being managed and run by Gracenote. They no longer have a public API, and will not allow applications direct access unless there will be "significant ticket sales". Their affiliate program is being funnelled through [CJ Affiliate](http://www.cj.com/). More information about the affiliate program can be found [here](http://www.fandango.com/affiliateprogram), and more information about Gracenote can be found [here](http://developer.tmsapi.com/io-docs). I hope this helps!